# Error in static member function instantiated from

Tags: ros, c++, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there !

I don't really find a title to my question, but when I try to compile the package I get the folowing errors, I don't know exactly the problem:

[image: image description]

```
Building CXX object columbot/CMakeFiles/MainController.dir/src/MainController.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_client.h:33:0,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/columbot/src/MainController.cpp:8:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = staubli::command]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_traits.h:97:104:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = staubli::command]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_client.h:90:71:   instantiated from ‘bool ros::ServiceClient::call(Service&) [with Service = staubli::command]’
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/columbot/src/MainController.cpp:21:30:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_traits.h:52:40: error: ‘const struct staubli::command’ has no member named ‘__getServerMD5Sum’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = staubli::command]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_traits.h:79:103:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::md5sum() [with M = staubli::command]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_client_options.h:94:5:   instantiated from ‘void ros::ServiceClientOptions::init(const string&, bool, const M_string&) [with Service = staubli::command, std::string = std::basic_string<char>, ros::M_string = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:1153:5:   instantiated from ‘ros::ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient(const string&, bool, const M_string&) [with Service = staubli::command, std::string = std::basic_string<char>, ros::M_string = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >]’
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/columbot/src/MainController.cpp:176:74:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/service_traits.h:47:43: error: ‘__s_getServerMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘staubli::command’
make[2]: *** [columbot/CMakeFiles/MainController.dir/src/MainController.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [columbot/CMakeFiles/MainController.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

And these are the concerning files:

Package 1: staubli
CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3) project(staubli)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   roscpp   rospy   std_msgs )

include_directories(   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

link_directories(   /home/jros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/   ${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

add_library(soapC src/soapC.cpp) add_library(Server0 src/soapCS8ServerV0Proxy.cpp) add_library(Server1 src/soapCS8ServerV1Proxy.cpp) add_library(Server3 src/soapCS8ServerV3Proxy.cpp) add_library(stdsoap2 src/stdsoap2.cpp) add_library(tx60l src/TX60L.cpp)

add_executable(staubli_controller src/controller.cpp) target_link_libraries(staubli_controller ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(staubli_controller ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  Server0 Server1 Server3 soapC stdsoap2 tx60l)

target_link_libraries(staubli_controller soapC) target_link_libraries(staubli_controller Server0) target_link_libraries(staubli_controller Server1) target_link_libraries(staubli_controller Server3) target_link_libraries(staubli_controller stdsoap2) target_link_libraries(staubli_controller tx60l)
```

[commande.h](http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Staubli/srv/cpp/staubli/command.h)

Package 2: columbot
CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3) 

project(columbot)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   roscpp   rospy   std_msgs staubli) 

include_directories(   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ) 

add_executable(MainController src/MainController.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MainController ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

[MainController.cpp](http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/columbot/src/MainController.cpp)

I'm using ROS-Hydro in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206203/error-in-static-member-function-instantiated-from-.../) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2015-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2015-03-29**:
could you add your CMakeFile please ?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-29**:
@Maya I just update my question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-31**:
I think it would be helpful if you didn't use a screenshot to show the error. Just copy/paste the console output, and format it properly using the `101010` button while editing your question.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-31**:
OK @gvdhoorn I did

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-31**:
You can probably coalesce all source files into a single library (with the exception of your main node), and then use a single `target_link_libraries(..)`, instead of the many -- single file -- libraries you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you are seeing is most likely caused by the fact that the `Staubli` pkg contains C++ code generated by a really old version of `gencpp`. The code is in the `Staubli/srv/gencpp` folder. At least, that is the case on the Subversion server you [linked](http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Staubli/).

In-source builds / code generation were common / accepted practice back then, but with Catkin it is preferable to do an out-of-source build.

I think you should either remove the `Staubli/srv/gencpp` and build everything using `rosmake`, or do a proper Catkin migration of the involved packages (see [catkin 0.6.11 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 1 (legacy) » Building messages, services or actions](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_msgs.html) for the msg/srv generation part).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-31**:
oh thank you, you are right.
I re-generate the `service` and it works.
But the question is what makes you know that the problem is the old version of `gencpp` ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-01**:
Experience, knowledge of the two build systems and of `gencpp`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I might be wrong but if I understand correctly, you're staubli package is a ROS package you created. You need to link it in your `columbot` (great name btw) CMakeList, because it can't find it.

I would guess something like :

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   roscpp   rospy   std_msgs     your_staubli_package)
```

And don't forget to put this after your `add_executable(MainController src/MainController.cpp)` :

```
target_link_libraries(MainController ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2015-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-29**:
yes this is what I do actually .

Unfourtunatly it doesn't work I get the same error !

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2015-03-29**:
Can you find your staubli package. Try `rospack find staubli`, what's the output ?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-29**:
Yes the package staubli works fine.

This is what I get:

```
ros@ros:~$ rospack find staubli
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/staubli
```

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2015-03-29**:
Okay sorry, end of my knowledge :p. I don't know your code but I think you might have a mistake then more than in the Cmakes. Again, I don't really know sorry :S

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-30**:
Thank you anyways (y)